# how do I update angularjs fullcalendar when the calendar is hidden with ng-show

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

When I add elements to the eventsource, the two way binding only seems to work when the calendar is visible. How do I get the two way binding to work when the calendar is hidden?

Html

```
<div id="timeOffBody" class="region-calendar" ng-show="!isBottomPanelVisible()">
    <div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" calendar="topCalendar" class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
</div>
```

Relevant JS

```
    $scope.existingRequests = [];
    $scope.pendingRequests = [];
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.existingRequests, $scope.pendingRequests];
    $scope.addNewRequestToPendingArray = function (request) {
        $scope.pendingRequests.push(request);
    };
   $scope.isBottomPanelVisible = function () {
        return (($scope.selectedStart != null) && ($scope.selectedEnd != null));
    }
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ek8wOTfxRnthHRjjO0Fe?p=preview). In the plunker example, you can see that the calendar is only updated when its container is visible, but the scope array of events is being added to even when hidden.

Comment: it shouldn't be matter with ng-show

Comment: yeah its weird.. I will try and make a fiddle or something later If I cannot figure it out. If I remove the ng-show then it works fine. But with it, the new elements do not show

Comment: you might wanna put it into plunker

Comment: Read somewhere that Angular tries to parses the DOM for the bindings. Would you be able to try to show the calendar, update then hide it again afterwards and see what happens?

Comment: @maxisam plunker created : http://plnkr.co/edit/ek8wOTfxRnthHRjjO0Fe?p=preview

Comment: I guess it is because UI Calendar use fullcalendar.js And it is not in AngularJS region, so it doesn't work when it is hidden.

Comment: yeah it looks like fullcalendar doesnt like adding events when its hidden. I will probably need to re render the events after the fact

Comment: Yes. It's because when it's going to render an element, it checks if its visible. You can see it here: https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/dist/fullcalendar.js#L7148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried it. It is because UI Calendar use fullcalendar.js And it is not in AngularJS region, so it doesn't work when it is hidden.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/COmCcf7g9DcyRs9HK5Ww?p=preview)

The idea is simple. inject `uiCalendarConfig` to your controller

and use it like `uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', $scope.events )`

Comment: I just updated the example, so it works as you want.